# AVSpeechSynthesizer get current position

Tags: ios, avspeechsynthesizer

I have a large block of text to be read by `AVSpeechSynthesizer`.
Is it possible to get the current position of audio playing in `AVSpeechSynthesizer` and playback later from the same position even after user has terminated the application by storing the audio playback position?

Comment: I just did a quick look, but could `AVSpeechUtterance` (given in the delegate methods) be what you're looking for?

Comment: You just use the delegate methods of AVSpeechUtterence and see this link http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/26424?m=16429914#16429914

Answer (score 0):

You can have the `AVSpeechSynthesizer` notify you through the `AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate` methods. From the [documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate_Ref/Reference/Reference.html)

```
– speechSynthesizer:didCancelSpeechUtterance:
– speechSynthesizer:didContinueSpeechUtterance:
– speechSynthesizer:didFinishSpeechUtterance:
– speechSynthesizer:didPauseSpeechUtterance:
– speechSynthesizer:didStartSpeechUtterance:
– speechSynthesizer:willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString:utterance:
```

You could use the `…willSpeakRange…` to keep track of where you are in your text.
In [this tutorial](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/01/08/synthesized-speech-from-text.html) it is used to highlight the current word.